# Is there a way to find key fields that cointain a specific substring in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, find, key, document, substr

I've looked into many solutions but all of them include finding substrings in **field values**. I have a collection that has over 3M docs, and some of them have date fields, but not all of them, nor the same number of fields each. For instance, one may have *"FirstDate"* and *"LastDate"*, others may contain just *"Date"* and others may not contain *any date fields* at all.

What I want to do is querying all documents that have the **word/substring "date"** in their **field keys**. In other words, query all key fields that contain the substr "date". For example:

```
db.collection.find({ *date* : { $exists : true } })
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
```

(I know * is wrong but it's just for illustration)

I've tried using `.find()`, `.aggregate()` and `$regex`, but all the syntaxes I've tried make no sense at all...

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using an aggregation pipeline. Let's suppose your collection looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    property: true,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    firstDate: "First date"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    lastDate: "Last name"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    date: "date"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    property: true
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    name: "Name"
  }
]
```

First you have to create a property with an array of keys and values, so you can later filter by the keys. This can be done by using `$objectToArray` in an `$addFields`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      keysAndValues: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT",
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

If you pass `$$ROOT` to it you will be creating an array with all the documents keys and values. So your data at this point will look like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "keysAndValues": [
      {
        "k": "_id",
        "v": 1
      },
      {
        "k": "property",
        "v": true
      }
    ],
    "property": true
  },

  ...

  {
    "_id": 6,
    "keysAndValues": [
      {
        "k": "_id",
        "v": 6
      },
      {
        "k": "name",
        "v": "Name"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Name"
  }
]
```

So you can now add a `$match` stage using `$regex` to filter by keys like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      keysAndValues: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT",
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "keysAndValues.k": {
        $regex: "date",
        $options: "i",
        
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

At this point, you already would have the desired result, all the documents that have the word `date` in the keys, then you could just unset the property you create to make filtering possible, `keysAndValues`, to clean up the data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      keysAndValues: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT",
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "keysAndValues.k": {
        $regex: "date",
        $options: "i",
        
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: 'keysAndValues' },
]);
```

After this your final result will be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "firstDate": "First date"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "lastDate": "Last name"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "date": "date"
  }
]
```

You can see a working example on this playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/U5FjTOVQIwb